How could I generate a large 3D mesh from a 2D texture at runtime?
I have a simple black and white texture, where white is a biome, and black is outside of the biome. I want to create a mesh at runtime that is the same shape as the white region and has a predetermined height. I already have a function to covert world coordinates to texture coordinates.
Biome Map Texture:


You would need to convert the texture into vertices to be used by the mesh, then create one dynamically see this unfortunately I don't know how to do that, but I can give you those links in case it helps.

Your question isn't specific enough. What do you mean by "predetermined height"? Do you want the mesh to be flat with curved edges? How large would your biome mesh be? How would multiple biomes be combined into one scene?
